# Javascript variable copying and data being overwritten in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I already have a solution, but I want to understand the *why*.

```
var returnObj = {};
//declare object
var copyObj = {};
    for (var k in data.data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.data[k].offerId.length; i++) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(data.data[k].offerId[i])) {
                (function() {
                    var offerId = data.data[k].offerId[i];
                    var verticalId = k;

                    copyObj = obj[offerId];

                    //this does not work - overwrites similar object in array
                    if (returnObj[offerId] !== undefined) {
                        copyObj.value = 'something';
                        returnObj['copy'] = copyObj;
                    } else {
                        copyObj.value = 'something else';
                        returnObj[offerId] = copyObj;
                    }
                })();
            }
         }
     }
```

So my question is, what is going on with the scope and the variable reference that causes my attempt at creating a new slot in the array for an object that already exists, to overwrite the already existing object in the array? My `copyObj.value` will be the `something` at both `returnObj['copy']` and `returnObj[offerId]`.

I have a solution already, and that is to use `angular.copy()`, but I wanted to know why updating the `copyObj` would affect the previously stored value?

Is there any other way to copy the object (instead of using `angular.copy()`)?

Comment: The reason this happens is because both variables reference the same `Object`. You would need to create a new object and copy all the properties of the original object to the new object.

Comment: Ok yes, that makes sense, but if I put `var copyObj = {}; copyObj = obj[offerId]` inside the loop, it still does not work for me. Is that because I am not then copying over every property to the new `copyObj`? Does javascript require manual copying of each item in an object instead of automatically doing it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You would have to use `var copyObj = {}; copyObj.someProp = obj[offerId].someProp; copyObj.otherProp = obj[offerId].otherProp;` etc. Much easier to just use `angular.copy()`. :)

Comment: You can loop over the properties of an object like so: `for(var prop in obj[offerId]) {`

Comment: That helps, thank you. How can I promote the comment as an answer?

Comment: Don't worry about it...glad I could help!